# Algebraic description of orthogonal projections in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am looking for a good synthetic and clear article presenting an algebraic description of the orthonormal projection in $\mathbb{R^2}$ compared to a line.

If you encounter one on the internet or anywhere else, I would be gratefull

Comment: "Algebraic description"? What is that? Give an example, please.

Comment: Search for "orthonormal projection",  watch some of the suggested videos, visit the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29 ).